# replace strings associate to certain ID

Tags: linux, bash

If in input.txt I would like to replace the element of the last column only with the string "P" for rows that have an ID equal or grater than 4000, how can I do?

i.e I would like to replace for only the first (ID = 4304) and third row (ID = 4000) the last element ("N" and "C") with "P".

input.txt

```
4304,N,-9.700,-7.680,58.330,-2.3,N
2940,S,-10.440,-3.450,54.270,2.2,S
4000,C,-13.655,-13.730,59.405,-1.5,C
2931,C,-9.910,-2.420,57.610,0.2,C
```

output.txt

```
4304,N,-9.700,-7.680,58.330,-2.3,P
2940,S,-10.440,-3.450,54.270,2.2,S
4000,C,-13.655,-13.730,59.405,-1.5,P
2931,C,-9.910,-2.420,57.610,0.2,C
```

How I can do? Thnaks!

Answer (score 1):

Something like can do the work:

```
awk -F, '$1=="4304" || $1=="4000" {$NF="P"}1 ' OFS=, input.txt >output.txt
```